# Python requests get freezes if server sends response after 4 or 5 minutes

Tags: python, python-requests

I use requests.get to get data through an API. The format of the api call is,

```
requests.get('https://www.yyy.com/zzz/aaa/', auth = HTTPBasicAuth('dddd', '')).
```

The server has to process the data before sending the response and so usually this takes anywhere from 2 to 6 minutes. This works perfectly fine in my laptop [*Windows 10*] where I have installed Anaconda env for python.

However, when I try the same code in a cloud PC [*Microsoft 365 Cloud PC - Windows 11*], I only get a response when the server sends the response within 4 minutes and any response that takes more than 4 minutes to process at the server side is never received.

The server side technical person looked at the logs and said that the connection is closed by my machine. I researched online and there are posts mentioning that this could be due to the TLS/ HTTP keep alive timeout settings in windows. According to a few of the posts, if there is no activity in a connection for 4 minutes, then windows closes the connection.

I am not an expert with networking and I was wondering if anyone has faced and resolved this issue. I have no idea how this works in my Laptop with a windows 10 env but does not in the Cloud PC with Windows 11 - where only the requests where server takes more than 4 minutes to respond is not received.

I have tried explicitly mentioning headers like the request is from a browser and I have also tried setting up a session in requests and then requesting the data but none of them worked.

Comment: What is source of data? Is this sync process

Comment: no it's nto a sync process. Our vendor holds some data for which they have given this api - which we use to get the said data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this in python using requests_toolbelt.

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters.socket_options import TCPKeepAliveAdapter

url = '...'
session = requests.Session()
keep_alive = TCPKeepAliveAdapter(idle=120, count=20, interval=30)
session.mount(url, keep_alive)

response = session.get(url)
```

I unfortunately lost the URL where I found this solution so I am unable to credit the original post/user.